# How to find a company with max max sum of orders during a period in postgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to find a company with max sum of orders during a period? Not max single order but a sum of orders during any period i want? I need to return CustAccount

I've tried something like that but it doesn't work

SELECT ct."CustAccount", max(m)

FROM "CustTrans" as ct

group by "CustAccount", "Amount"

order by "Amount" desc

(select sum(ct."Amount"))

from "CustTrans" as ct

WHERE ct."TransDate" BETWEEN '01/01/2000' and '31/01/2022')) as m

[Table i have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMMQ9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something like

SELECT MAX(CustAccount),
FROM CustTrans
Where TransDate BETWEEN '01/01/2000' and '31/01/2022'
ORDER BY TransDate ASC

Comment: im just getting max CustAccount id with that request, thx for answer tho ^^

Comment: Hey, are you specifying the ID? As my query should only show you the CustAccount column. Whatever column you want the max of just plop it in the MAX(column here) and it should work :)

Comment: i want to get max sum of orders during a period and if i insert "Amount" in your query instead of  CustAccount i also just getting max amount, but not max SUM of amounts during the period. Also "ORDER BY TransDate ASC" dnt work w/o group by. Sorry if i cant explain correctly :)

Comment: SELECT MAX(CustAccount), SUM(Amount) FROM TableName Where Date Between 'x' and 'x' Group By CustAccount Order By Sum ASC

Comment: https://prnt.sc/1uobupj <-- last question sir, how can i leave only biggest sum now? only first row

Comment: Well you could order by amount DESC which would show you the highest amount first. I think that should work for you.

Comment: Works nearly as i want to! Thanks a lot and good luck :)